# C# MongoDb Dependency Injection & Inversion of Control

Tags: c#, mongodb, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I am working with a Mongo Database for a custom CMS I am trying to create. I am relatively new to MVC, though not unfamiliar with OOP Languages, and I do grasp - vaguely I must admit - the concepts of Dependency Injection, and how Inversion of Control better tops the former off (in most cases).

I have tried looking for several days around the Internet of examples that could help facilitate me through creating my own DIs or IoC container, but to no avail yet. From my understanding so far, MVC (and C# in general) rely heavily on conventions, hence my question.

So far, using an example of a MongoDB University MVC Project, I have this Model setup that helps me connect with my mongo database:

```
public class BlogContext
{
    private static readonly MongoCredential Credentials = MongoCredential.CreateCredential("admin", "root", "*****");
    private static readonly MongoServerAddress MongoServerAddress = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
    private static readonly MongoClientSettings MongoClientSettings = new MongoClientSettings
    {
        Credentials = new[] { Credentials },
        Server = MongoServerAddress
    };
    public const string DATABASE_NAME = "testdb";
    public const string POSTS_COLLECTION_NAME = "cmstest";
    public const string USERS_COLLECTION_NAME = "users";

    // This is ok... Normally, they would be put into
    // an IoC container.
    private static readonly IMongoClient _client;
    private static readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

    static BlogContext()
    {
        _client = new MongoClient(MongoClientSettings);
        _database = _client.GetDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    }

    public IMongoClient Client => _client;

    public IMongoCollection<Article> Articles => _database.GetCollection<Article>(POSTS_COLLECTION_NAME);

    public IMongoCollection<User> Users => _database.GetCollection<User>(USERS_COLLECTION_NAME);
}
```

And **for every controller action, or whenever I need to access my database, I initialize a BlogContext class** and connect like so

```
var blogContext = new BlogContext();
await blogContext.Articles.UpdateOneAsync(x => x.Id == id, update);
```

**I do know (and I've read several times) that Mongo uses a Connection Pool and it's thread-safe.** I am looking for a better way to implement this. Be it by creating an Interface and using Dependency Injection, or by using an IoC Container, as even the class comment suggests.

I have read about implementations of IoC via Castle Windsor or Unity, but what I am looking for is an **example**. This way, perhaps I might be able to use this to create my own IoC Container.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dependency injection is a form of inversion of control, they are not competing concepts - one is not "better" than the other. Mark Seemann's book [Dependency Injection in .Net](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net) is a great learning resource, and contains examples of both DIY dependency injection, and examples using popular frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to get a look at that book in order to get a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using ServiceStack.Funq

Your global.asax should look something like this

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Funq container = new Funq.Container();

        container.Register<IMyType>(c => new MyType());
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
    }
```

and your controller

```
public class ExampleController : ServiceStackController
{
   public IMyType MyType {get;set;}

   public ActionResult Index(){
      return View();
   }
}
```

`MyType` will be autowired by the IoC Container.

Comment: You will need ServiceStack.Mvc package for this. It has a dependency on ServiceStack package which included ServiceStack.Funq. Note that ServiceStack v3.9.71 is the last non commercial version. ServiceStack v4 is commercial but can be used with some limitations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll have to try it out and see if I can get a better grasp of IoC Containers

Comment: Maybe these can help:  1. http://joelabrahamsson.com/inversion-of-control-an-introduction-with-examples-in-net/
2. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of mature IoC containers out there with extensive MVC support, so no need to implement your own. You can look into [performance](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) and [feature](http://featuretests.apphb.com/DependencyInjection.html) benchmarks, select some top dogs and look for MVC integration in docs. Usually example is included.